# alpaca forms and tabs

Tags: tabs, alpacajs

I am new to alpaca forms and looking at the following requirement -

Alpaca form supports table - where we can add multiple rows of similar type.
Is there any way we can have this in tab format instead of tables. Which means each row in a table can be represented in the form of tab. So, three rows means three tabs.

Please let me know, if you need further information

Comment: I know this is very late response,  check the link it could help http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/wizards.html